# Drawing pacman shape with single arc() function call?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Trying to figure out why I can't draw a pacman shape given my current understanding of how the arc() function works.

When I try the following code in Chrome/Firefox, it draws a complete circle, which isn't what I would expect. I suspect it might have something to do with the non-zero winding rule? My guess is that the -45 is being internally normalized, causing the resulting angle sweep to become CCW instead of CW. But when I tested that assumption by changing the final arg to be CCW, nothing changed in Chrome (However FF behavior was different in that nothing was drawn)

```
// draw pacman shape
ctx.arc(200,200,50, -45 * DEGREES, 45 * DEGREES, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

Full example:
http://pastebin.com/2ZkJXgJU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what your looking for:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0.25 * Math.PI, 1.25 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0.75 * Math.PI, 1.75 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
ctx.fill();
```

source: http://simeonvisser.hubpages.com/hub/HTML5-Tutorial-Drawing-Circles-and-Arcs

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question and has already been answered but I think there's an easier way to draw pac-man with a single arc.

```
// An arc with an opening at the right for the mouth
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0.2 * Math.PI, 1.8 * Math.PI, false);

// The mouth
// A line from the end of the arc to the centre
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);

// A line from the centre of the arc to the start
ctx.closePath();

// Fill the pacman shape with yellow
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fill();

// Draw the black outline (optional)
ctx.stroke();

// Draw the eye
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
ctx.fill();
```

The accepted answer will work but it used two semi circles rather than a single arc. This method also gives you the option to draw an outline.

Comment: Nice approach :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your forth and fifth arguments are wrong, they range from -Math.PI to Math.PI, not with degrees.

a trick I used to make 'pacman'  like shapes are by setting the size of the stroke equal to the radius of the circle

```
ctx.lineWidth = 50;
ctx.arc(200,200,50,Math.PI*2.1,Math.PI*1.7, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/8JaLY/2/

Comment: Thanks Xeli, my args are actually in radians (DEGREES is a constant that will convert) though I tweaked your example, and it gave me exactly what I was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/8JaLY/3/

Comment: Oops, though I just realized there's a bug in my DEGREES assignment. I mean to say var DEGREES = Math.PI / 180; (accidentally multiplied instead) :]

Comment: @joeycato you're welcome, if you're satisfied with the answer please do tag it as 'answered' :)

Comment: @joeycato I think changing the above trick to this: `ctx.arc(200,200,50,Math.PI*2.1,Math.PI*1.8, false);` will returns better and similar shape to pacman.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath to find out what is PATH

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var centerX = 100;
var centerY = 100;
var radius = 50; 
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
ctx.arc(
  centerX,centerY,radius,
  -Math.PI/4,Math.PI/4, // -45 deg to 45 deg
  true //anticlockwise
 );
ctx.lineTo(centerX,centerY);
ctx.stroke();//border
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```